# Good-to-Bad color scale without green

Tags: color, color-theory

I'm new to the community but I was wondering if you guys could help me out. Typically when someone want to display a scale of good-to-bad they show something like:

[image: red to green color gradient]

Red is bad and green is good, with yellow being somewhere in between. What I am faced with however is that all options are bad, so I cannot use green. I also have a wide range of levels of bad with the low end being somebody being rude and the upper end being murder. I was thinking about maybe using purples or blues to increase the spread, but, being completely new to any graphic design, I'm unsure. Like this:

[image]

The colors would never be displayed directly next to each other, so a perfect gradient isn't necessary. Any tips or help at all is appreciated!

Comment: Including what you're actually creating the scale for could greatly improve the suggestions for what should be used.

Comment: For what its worth Japanese use blue instead of green

Comment: Whatever color combination you choose, please ensure it is accessible to colorblind individuals, either by choosing colors with different brightnesses, or by providing a non-color UI indication as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Lucien has the right of it. If you need only a color scale (and not a graphic scale) then perhaps a red to yellow stepped blend or a solid red to transparent blend.

It seems to me that any color other than red (bad) to yellow (caution) will not translate to different degrees of "bad".

[image]

Comment: One option could be using black instead of white.

Answer (score 8):

If its all from bad to very bad, in all shades of bad, why not use a single color, uhm... let's say... **red**, for everything, and come up with this bad rating scale. Some ideas below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately it does have to be separate colors not designs.

Comment: A variation on this would be something like the Consumer Reports hollow circle scale (not sure of the name - you should be able to see it on their car ratings (I haven't looked in a long time)).  A filled red circle is bad, a half filled red circle is half bad, a hollow read circle is meh.  You could also pick two colors (say, red for bad and grey for *neutral*) and extend the scale somewhat.