# Cross-culture Bad-to-Good scale colouring

Tags: color-theory

I need to produce a scale going from "bad to good". Usually red stands for bad and green for good. However, the target audience is global and in some cultures, red is actually good (e.g. China stocks are red when they go up, marry in red dresses and give presents in red envelops whereas stocks go down are green).

Are Asians and/or Chinese used to understand red as also bad in a good-to-bad scale? Is there a more "universal" colouring that could be understood everywhere?

[image: Red to green - Bad-to-Good Scale]

Comment: No, there is no scale that can be entirely culturally universally understood.

Comment: See this post for some ideas-  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143922/good-to-bad-color-scale-without-green       possibly a single color with varying shades?